# parse JSON with ServiceStack

Tags: c#, json

How to parse this json string? I tried to put in in Dictionary

```
var dictionary = text.FromJson<Dictionary<string, string>>();
```

but the array is not parsed.

```
{"v":[[9,-1],[9,-44,1]]}
```

Comment: You've got the wrong shape for ServiceStack it's a `Dictionary<string,List<List<int>>>`. You can also parse JSON dynamically in ServiceStack JsonSerializer by using `JsonObject`e.g: https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text/blob/master/tests/ServiceStack.Text.Tests/UseCases/CentroidTests.cs#L132

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this class

```
public class Root
{
     public  List<List<int>> v;
}

var result = text.FromJson<Root>();
```

**EDIT**

Since your json string has changed, I prepared a sample using [Json.Net](http://json.codeplex.com/)

```
string json = @"{ v: [ [ 9, 16929, 1, 856, 128, '123', 'hello', {'type': 'photo', 'attach1': '123_456'} ] ] } ";
var obj = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);

foreach (var arr in obj["v"])
{
    foreach(var item in arr)
    {
        if (item is JValue)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine(">>> " + item["type"]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I forgot to say that structure can be also: { v: [ [ 9, 16929, 1, 856, 128, '123', 'hello', {'type': 'photo', 'attach1': '123_456'} ] ] }

Comment: @igla Your array contains ints strings and complex objects `{'type': 'photo', 'attach1': '123_456'}`. So I don't think you can deserialize it to a typesafe class. handle it dynamically. If you are open to use [Json.Net](http://json.codeplex.com/) I can post an answer.

Comment: Not sure if that is possible... Have that data a compleat structure? That example shows just that there can come much mote complex structures

Comment: thank you very much! I see that it's more comfortable to use Json.Net that servicestack)

Answer (score 3):

You use the wrong structure. You value is a multi demensional array and no string. Try the type
 `Dictionary<String, List<List<int>>>`

```
var dictionary = text.FromJson< Dictionary<String, List<List<int>>>>();
```